# INNODB Cascade Syntax / Logic Problem

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-error-1005

I have a problem with an SQL database I'm creating.  I'm trying to switch it over to use INNODB but I can't seem to get the syntax (or possibly logic) correct for cascading.

Here's a [part of the code erroring](http://pastebin.com/m7216314f).  It does not like line 40.

Error output in the usual cryptic (to me at least) form:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 36: Can't create table './school/staff.frm' (errno: 150)
```

Edit:

Here's the [whole SQL file](http://pastebin.com/m45174ae7) I'm trying to pipe in if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign keys have to be indexes. (**role.name**)

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `role` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: I had actually already tried adding a INDEX name line to it, which didn't work.  And it seems neither does your suggestion :(.

Still outputs this: ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 37: Can't create table './school/staff.frm' (errno: 150)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean for the "role" column's foreign key constraint to be using the name instead of the ID?  It looks like the following line (line 43):

```
FOREIGN KEY (role) REFERENCES role(name)
```

should be:

```
FOREIGN KEY (role) REFERENCES role(id)
```

This executes without errors.

Alternatively, the "staff.role" column's data type (line 40, role INT NOT NULL) could be changed to CHAR(30) NOT NULL.